# Reusing an extisting Provisioning Profile in XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, provisioning-profile

Some context.

A developer in the team using XCode 8 has archived and exported (actually expoterd an ipa though I think this is irrelevant) an iOS app using the automatic provisioning settings in XCode 8.

I would like to now submit our app to the app store.

If I go through the archive process with the automatic settings, XCode creates a NEW provisioning profile and invalidates the existing one.

How can I continue to use the automatic features of XCode 8 while also re-using the provisioning profile already created?

My aim is to simply package an app to the app store using an existing profile. Or rather, package an app WITHOUT invalidating an existing profile.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done only if you still have the certificate with the private key for signing the package.

If it is available then you have to add it to your Mac using the Keychain Access tool.

As soon as you add the certificate then you can use the existing profile for signing the package.

If the certificate is no more available then you can modify the existing profiles on Apple Dev site in order to use a brand new certificate generated following the step by step procedure available on the iOS Certificates section of the Apple Dev site. In this case you have to re-download the provisioning profiles in Xcode settings.

Comment: thanks Cristallo. I guess I have a follow up question. Uising XCode 8's automatica signining stuff, if i archive and push with a new profile created by XC will it automatically invalidate the existing profile?

Comment: I do not let xcode to choose the signing identity ... I usually set the code signing identity explicitly. I guess that it is trying to generate a new one because the old one cannot be use, due to the private key missing issue.

Comment: hmm thanks Cristallo .But do you know if I do archive with a new profile, will the existing one still be valid?

Comment: if you generate a new profile the old reaming valid until it will be deleted from the Apple dev site. If you modify the old one then all developers have to update their mac in order to use the modified one.

Comment: obviously the old packages (signed with the old certificate) remain always valid

Comment: Just to clarify, they will remain valid as long as you don't revoke the old certificate.  Revoking the old certificate will invalidate old builds.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to the old (much maligned) "Fix Issues" button, using Automatic code signing in Xcode 8+ will not affect existing certs and provisioning profiles.  Using the automatic code signing should leave the existing profile and cert in place and the other developers can either continue to use their own cert / profile without a problem.

If you are using a code repository (you should be), when you check in your code signing changes to the project, any other developers will now have auto code signing in their copies of the project. If they have an existing, valid cert and profile on their machine, it may use those.  If not, or if for any reason the cert / profile become invalid, Xcode will generate a new one.